# Running txt files in different editors by just writing programms name

Tags: java, runtime.exec

i got two questions. 
Where is the directory the Method `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` gets its resources from?

if i am calling `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe")`, why does it start the windows editor? Where does java gets the .exe source from?

based on this question, i have to let the user choose, if he wants to open a file in an editor, which editors he prefers, and wants to use. He only writes in something like `notepad.exe` or `ultraedit.exe` and the choosen file will be opened in the editor written down here. At the moment, i am opening a file with this Method

```
public void open(String path) {
    try {
        if(new File(path).exists())
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe " + path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So as you can see every file will be opened within the notepad. But i need to have something like this :

```
public void open(String program, String path) {
    try {
        if(new File(path).exists())
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(program + " " + path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So is there any possibility to open txt files in different editors, by just calling their
.exe file?

Comment: `if(new File(path).exists())
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe " + path);`  I believe that will fail if there is a space in the `path`.  But overall, it is extremely fragile code.  Be sure to visit the Java World article linked from the [`exec` info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info) and implement the recommendations in order to save future pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Where does java gets the .exe source from?
```

Its not about java. check the `PATH` environment variables in you Operating systems. It has the path for all the exe files. 
Try this

1) open cmd

2) type `c:\> echo %PATH%`

the second will tell you the values of PATH variable

```
So is there any possibility to open txt files in different editors, by just calling their .exe file?
```

yes edit the PATH variable to include the path of you other editor's exe file ( use semicolon and then append the path to environment don't replace the existing string ), and the java program remains the same

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.exec()` gets its information from `PATH`. Any program found in there can be executed like you showed.